# Adding data to ObservableCollection in WPF

Tags: c#

I have some problem here. Here it is:
I have this class

```
public class NewsFeedResources
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<NewsFeedResources> _newsfeed = new ObservableCollection<NewsFeedResources>
    {

        new NewsFeedResources { Name = "Joe", Id = "1", Message="Foo" },
        new NewsFeedResources { Name = "Wandy", Id = "2", Message="Bar" },
        new NewsFeedResources { Name = "Yuliana", Id = "3", Message="Baz" },
        new NewsFeedResources { Name = "Hardi", Id = "4", Message="Baz" },

    };

    public static ObservableCollection<NewsFeedResources> newsFeedResources
    { get { return _newsfeed; }

    }
}
```

If I have another data such as

Name=John, Id=5, Message="Stack overflow"
Name=Jane, Id=6, Message="Hello world"

How can I add the data into the class, but not from the constructor? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` exposes the [`Collection<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404.aspx) Method:

> Adds an object to the end of the Collection.

So you'd have:

```
_newsfeed.Add(new NewsFeedResources {Name = "John",
                                     Id = 5,
                                     Message = "Stack overflow"});
_newsfeed.Add(new NewsFeedResources {Name = "Jane",
                                     Id = 6,
                                     Message = "Hello world"});
```

<sup>(typed from memory)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

call a function from constructor or anywhere as u like and add items like below

```
NewsFeedResources NFR=new  NewsFeedResources(){Name=John, Id=5, Message="Stack overflow"};
_newsfeed.add(NFR);
 NewsFeedResources NFR1 =new  NewsFeedResources(){Name=Jane, Id=6, Message="Hello world"};
_newsfeed.add(NFR);
```